# How do I call protected methods using class helper?

Tags: delphi, oop, class-helpers

Suppose we have a classes with method which is potentially very useful, but not available due protected scope:

```
unit Sealed;

interface

type
  TGeneral = class(TObject)
    { this method is useful, but not available }
    protected procedure Useful; virtual;
  end;

  TSpecific1 = class(TGeneral)
    { some descendants override `Useful` method }
    protected procedure Useful; override;
  end;

  TSpecific2 = class(TGeneral)
    { and some dont, but inherit `Useful`ness from the parent }
  end;
```

I know two old-school ways to reach out for such method, both are involving an inheritance and typecast. Both approaches should works the same with the basic case #1 and advanced polymorphic case #2.

```
program CallingSite;

uses Sealed;

function GetInstance: TGeneral;
begin
  { !PSEUDO! makes compiler happy about the rest of code }
  // depending on use case supposed to return an instance of `TGeneral`
  // or any of its descendants - `TSpecific1`, `TSpecific2`
end;

type
  { this makes a current module a "friend" for `TGeneral` }
  TFriend = class(TGeneral)
  end;

procedure Case1;
var
  { holds an instance of `TGeneral` }
  General: TGeneral;
begin
  General := GetInstance;
  { protected method is available for "friend" via static cast }
  TFriend(General).Useful;  // compiles!
end;

type
  TIntroducer = class(TGeneral)
  { this "reintroduces" `Useful` method to public scope }
  public procedure Useful; override;
  // this approach ought to work even with strict protected methods
  // !!! but I THINK it is UNSAFE to use on virtual and/or dynamic methods
  end;

procedure TIntroducer.Useful;
begin
  { and calls `Useful` via wrapper }
  inherited;
end;

procedure Case2;
var
  { polymorphic instance of any `TGeneral`'s descendant }
  Specific: TGeneral;
begin
  Specific := GetInstance;
  { protected method is callable via public wrapper, static cast again }
  TIntroducer(Specific).Useful; // compiles!
end;
```

I'd like to know:

- how to achieve the same result applying the power of class helpers?
- is it possible to call a private method with class helper as well?
- will be any differences between case #1 and case #2 due the fact what class helper augments the class scope, not an internal representation?
- how to invoke an original method from the one reintroduced in class helper w/o risking a recursion?

Also, please comment on remark about `TIntroducer` unsafety.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a helper as so :

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  TGeneral = class(TObject)
    protected procedure Useful; virtual;
  end;

  TSpecific2 = class(TGeneral)
  end;

  TSpecificHelper = class helper for TGeneral
  public
    procedure ExposedUseful;
  end;

implementation

procedure TGeneral.Useful;
begin
  WriteLn('general');
end;

procedure TSpecificHelper.ExposedUseful;
begin
  Useful;
end;    

end.
```

These can even be declared in separate units, for example :

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  TGeneral = class(TObject)
    protected procedure Useful; virtual;
  end;

implementation

procedure TGeneral.Useful;
begin
  WriteLn('general');
end;

end.
```

and separately

```
unit Unit3;

interface
uses
  Unit2;
type
  TSpecific2 = class(TGeneral)
  end;

  TSpecificHelper = class helper for TGeneral
  public
    procedure ExposedUseful;
  end;

implementation

procedure TSpecificHelper.ExposedUseful;
begin
  Useful;
end;

end.
```

And to test :

```
program Project1;


{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  //Unit2,  // either or
  Unit3;

var
  foo : TSpecific2;
begin
  foo := TSpecific2.Create;
  foo.ExposedUseful;
  Readln;
end.
```

Private members can be exposed in a similar way if you make the helper for the base class instead.  If in a different unit, a cast is required however.  For example :

```
// in Unit2
TGeneral = class(TObject)
    private
      procedure AlsoUseful;
    protected
      procedure Useful; virtual;
  end;

//in Unit3

  TSpecificHelper = class helper for TGeneral
  public
    procedure ExposedUseful;
    procedure ExposedAlsoUseful;
  end;

// ...
implementation

procedure TSpecificHelper.ExposedAlsoUseful;
begin
  TGeneral(self).AlsoUseful;
end;
```

As for polymorphism, you can really just test this out yourself.  The helper will apply to whatever descendent class your instance derives from:

```
  TSpecific1 = class(TGeneral)
    protected
      procedure Useful; override;
  end;

// ...

procedure TSpecific1.Useful;
begin
  WriteLn('specific 1');
end;
```

where

```
TSpecific2 = class(TSpecific1)
end;
```

Will produce output `specific 1` when called with the helper for the base class above.

**Note**
Starting with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, Class helpers can no longer access strict protected, strict private or private members. This "feature" was actually a compiler bug that Embarcadero has now fixed in Berlin.
Accessing plain protected members with helpers remains possible.

Comment: Thanks! So, it is not possible to retain original method name while avoiding a recursion?

Comment: And will polymorphism work without getting into dire details of `TSpecificN` implementation? eg: will helper be able to call virtual method?

Comment: @FreeConsulting No, the stack overflow should be pretty obvious if you try to use the same name.  Edited to answer your second question.

Comment: @FreeConsulting  With all of this said, suggest you also read this : http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/273